# C programming getchar()

Tags: c, getchar

I have two problems writing my code. The first problem I have is getting my getchar() to work if the user enters no text and just hits enter. I need to print an error if they do so and prompt the user to reenter the text in a loop until they do enter text. Is there any way to do so because everything I have tried has failed.
Here is the code I have for that section:

```
printf("Enter a text message: ");
while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
{
        text[i]= c;
        i++;
}
```

I am new to C so I am limited on ideas to fix my dilemma. As you can see I am setting the input equal to an array. This leads to my second problem, I need to limit the input to no more than 100 characters. But, instead of giving the user an error I need to just chop off the extra characters and just read the first 100.

Comment: Note: When using `c = fgetc()`, insure `int c` and not `char c`. This helps with `is...()` functions and distinguishes between `EOF` and the 256 different characters one may get.

Comment: Note: In 2 comments you ask to "recognize that there is no input".  This is tricky for a program to sense "no input". "No input" to me means not typing _anything_.  Rather than thinking "no input", think of it as _only_ pressing the <Enter> key.  Now code has _some_ input and can act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem is to use `fgets`. We can give limit to the input so that it doesn't read the extra characters after the given limit.

Refer this sample code. Here I am printing the string if the user is not pressing `Enter` key:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char str[100];
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    if(str[0] != '\n')
    {
        puts(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and the compiler I use doesn't allow fgets for some reason. So my instructor told me to use getchar(). It would be way easier if I could use it though.

Comment: Did you add `stdio.h` header file? Which platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: I used #include<stdio.h>. The compiler says that gets and fgets is dangerous and should not be used. I made sure to try both and my code looked identical to yours.

Comment: Avoid `gets()` at all costs.  `fgets()` is not  dangerous and fine to use.

Comment: Okay, I might have typed something in wrong. I will try fgets() again tomorrow and see if it takes it. Thank you so much!

Comment: `fgets` does not "remove" the extra characters. It simply doesn't read them. They're still in the input buffer, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 100

int main() {
  char text[MAXSIZE+1]; // one extra for terminating null character
  int i = 0;
  int c;

  while (1) {
    printf("Enter a text message: ");

    i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != '\r' && c != EOF) {
      if (i < MAXSIZE) {
        text[i]= c;
        i++;
      }
    }
    if (i > 0 || c == EOF)
      break;
    printf("Empty string not allowed.\n");
  }

  text[i] = '\0';

  printf("You entered: %s\n", text);

  return 0;
}
```

Test code to detect non-compliant system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  printf("Just hit enter: ");
  c = getchar();
  if (c == '\r')
    printf("\\r detected!!!\n");
  else if (c == '\n')
    printf("\\n detected.\n");
  else
    printf("Yikes!!!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you input. I will try something similar and see if it works out. For some reason I can't get the it to recognize that there is no input.

Comment: @ooga OP might be in an (IMO non-compliant) environment and receiving `"\r\n"` fooling  the empty string detection.

Comment: @chux Interesting idea. I'll post some code for the OP to test that out.

Comment: @user3822731 Try the test code above (the second block of code) and let me know what the result is. Also, try the other code again. I added a test for `'\r'`.

Comment: I think `|| c == EOF` is unnecessarily. case of `i == 0 && c == EOF` : It must be considered that there is no input.

Comment: The new code worked perfectly. Thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all getchar() can take only one character an input. It cannot take more than one character.

```
char c;
int total_characters_entered = 0;
do
{
    printf ("Enter a text message: ");
    c = getchar();

    if (c != '\n')
    {
        total_characters_entered++;
    }

} while (total_characters_entered <= 100);
```

I have written some code that will iterate in while loop until user has entered 100 characters excluding "Simple Enter without any text"

Please let me know if it does not satisfy your requirement. We will work on that.

Comment: To store all of the input I am using the array. It is stored fine and prints everything. For some reason I can't get it to recognize when there is no input and enter is the only thing put in.